# Gradient of $ct'$ axis in spacetime diagrams

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems

This is either an unimportant piece of information or it's meant to be obvious, but I can't find anywhere what the gradient of the $ct'$ axis in a spacetime diagram should be. I know that the $ct'=1$ and $x'=1$ axis ticks correspond to $\gamma$ on the $ct$ and $x$ axes respectively, but I'm not sure if that helps.

Comment: The gradient of $ct'$ with respect to what? $x$ or $x'$?

Comment: The angle between the $ct$ and $ct'$ axes is $\tan^{-1}(v/c)$. The proof is to see where the point $(t, 0)$ transforms to under the Lorentz transformations.